# need help in Simplifying a make file in C

Tags: c, makefile

i wrote a make file C
but i need to simplify it as much as possible because it's quite long
any help?

```
# Makefile for makedemo

bin/Debug/P3_MakeDemo: bin bin/Debug bin/obj bin/obj/ma.o bin/obj/mb.o bin/obj/mc.o bin/obj/md.o bin/obj/main.o
    gcc -o bin/Debug/P3_MakeDemo bin/obj/ma.o bin/obj/mb.o bin/obj/mc.o bin/obj/md.o bin/obj/main.o -Wall -g -pedantic --std=c99
    bin/Debug/P3_MakeDemo

bin/obj: bin/
    mkdir bin/obj

bin/Debug: bin/
    mkdir bin/Debug
bin:
    mkdir bin


bin/obj/ma.o: src/ma.c
    gcc -I include -c src/ma.c -o bin/obj/ma.o -Wall -g -pedantic --std=c99 

bin/obj/mb.o: src/mb.c
    gcc -I include -c src/mb.c -o bin/obj/mb.o -Wall -g -pedantic --std=c99

bin/obj/mc.o: src/mc.c
    gcc -I include -c src/mc.c -o bin/obj/mc.o -Wall -g -pedantic --std=c99

bin/obj/md.o: src/md.c
    gcc -I include -c src/md.c -o bin/obj/md.o -Wall -g -pedantic --std=c99

bin/obj/main.o: src/main.c
    gcc -I include -c src/main.c -o bin/obj/main.o -Wall -g -pedantic --std=c99

clean:
    rm -rf bin/Debug/P3_MakeDemo
    rm -rf bin/obj/ma.o
    rm -rf bin/obj/mb.o
    rm -rf bin/obj/mc.o
    rm -rf bin/obj/md.o
    rm -rf bin/obj/main.o
    rm -rf bin/obj
    rm -rf bin

debug_off:
    sed -i -e 's/#define DEBUG/#undef DEBUG/g' include/globals.h

debug_on:
    sed -i -e 's/#undef DEBUG/#define DEBUG/g' include/globals.h

dochtml:doc
    cd doc; doxygen

docclean:
    rm -rf doc/html

doc:
    mkdir doc

test: bin bin/Debug/test bin/obj bin/obj/ma.o bin/obj/mb.o bin/obj/mc.o bin/obj/md.o bin/Debug/test
    bin/Debug/test

bin/Debug/test:test/main.o
    gcc -l cunit -o bin/Debug/test bin/obj/ma.o bin/obj/mb.o bin/obj/mc.o bin/obj/md.o test/main.o -Wall -g -pedantic --std=c99

test/main.o: test/main.c
    gcc -I include -c test/main.c -o test/main.o -Wall -g -pedantic --std=c99

testclean:
    rm test/main.o
    rm bin/exec/test

.PHONY: test
```

Comment: what kind of 'make' do you use ?

Comment: Supposing that (to the best of your knowledge) the makefile works in all respects the way you want it to do, this sort of general "how do I make it better?" question belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not SO.

Comment: Each `make` has documentation that show how to use patterns and rules. Start with the chapter "Pattern rules".

Comment: Sorry bruno i didn’t get your question

Comment: check my answer for generic Makefile with no explicit .o block for individual files

Answer (score 0):

Make a generic variable based Makefile, so that when you modify one variable the files will be auto located and auto compiled

Below example allows you modify only `OBJS` variable all the corresponding files auto added to the final gcc or g++ command

means If you set `P3_MakeDemo.o ma.o` for `OBJS` it will auto pick `P3_MakeDemo.c` and `ma.c`

```
PROJECT_ROOT = $(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))

OBJS = P3_MakeDemo.o ma.o
CXX = g++
CC = gcc
BUILD_MODE = debug

ifeq ($(BUILD_MODE),debug)
    CFLAGS += -g
else ifeq ($(BUILD_MODE),run)
    CFLAGS += -O2
else
    $(error Build mode $(BUILD_MODE) not supported by this Makefile)
endif

all: P3_MakeDemo

P3_MakeDemo:    $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^

%.o:    $(PROJECT_ROOT)%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<

%.o:    $(PROJECT_ROOT)%.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -fr P3_MakeDemo $(OBJS)
```

when you run `make all` you will see similar output

```
make all 
gcc -c -g  -o P3_MakeDemo.o /project/P3_MakeDemo/P3_MakeDemo.c
gcc -c -g  -o ma.o /project/P3_MakeDemo/ma.c
g++ -o P3_MakeDemo P3_MakeDemo.o ma.o
```

This allows you add any number of .c or .cpp your project without changing much in Makefile script

if you don't want CPP/C++ then this file size can be even reduced in number of lines, the debug flag can also be removed which will again reduce number of lines